# Google Analytics PHP API Getting fullReferrer

Tags: google-analytics, php

I want to get fullReferrer using Google Analytics API with PHP.

And I tried as follows:

```
return $analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $profileId,
                                '7daysAgo',
                                'today',
                                'ga:sessions',
                                array('dimensions' => 'ga:fullReferrer',));
```

And here is my javascript code for sending data.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-86037456-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setReferrerOverride', 'facebook.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
         var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
         ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
```

And when I run php code I always get `(direct)` for fullReferrer.